# Move Elements on Magento 2 Product Page

Tags: layout, uielement

I have the Porto Theme installed on my website using Magento 2.2.5.
I would like to move a couple of Elements on the Product page but only for specific products.
I have attached a screenshot of how the page looks now

[image]

I need to move the **product.info.review** element and everything below it to the 3rd column under the related products block.
the layout is using **catalog_product_view.xml**
Code is:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright Â© 2018 Porto. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page layout="2columns-right" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="sidebar.additional">
            <block class="Smartwave\Porto\Block\Template" name="product_view_custom_block" before="-" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/custom_block.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
        <move element="product.info.stock.sku" destination="product.info.price" after="product.price.final"/>
        <move element="product.info.review" destination="product.info.main" after="product.info.price"/>
        <move element="catalog.product.related" destination="sidebar.additional" after="product_view_custom_block"/>
        <!--<referenceBlock name="catalog.product.related" remove="true"/>-->
        <move element="product.info.overview" destination="product.info.main" after="product.info.review"/>
        <referenceContainer name="after.body.start">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product_custom" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/product_custom.phtml" before="-"/>
            <block class="Smartwave\Porto\Block\Template" name="product_view_config" after="-" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/config.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
        <referenceContainer name="columns.top">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="prev_next_products" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/prev_next.phtml" before="-"/>
        </referenceContainer>
        <move element="prev_next_products" destination="product.info.main" before="-"/>
        <move element="page.main.title" destination="product.info.main" before="-"/>
        <referenceContainer name="product.info.social">
            <block class="Smartwave\Porto\Block\Template" name="product_view_addthis_links" after="-" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/addthis.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Smartwave\Porto\Block\RickSnippet" name="rich_snippet" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/rich_snippet.phtml" before="-"/>
            <block class="Smartwave\Porto\Block\Template" name="product_view_main_custom_block" ifconfig="porto_settings/product/main_custom_block" before="product.info.main" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/main_custom_block.phtml"/>
            <block class="Smartwave\Porto\Block\Template" name="product_view_main_custom_block2" after="-" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/main_custom_block2.phtml"/>
            <block class="Smartwave\Porto\Block\Template" name="product.clearer" after="product.info.media" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/clearer.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
        <move element="product_view_main_custom_block2" destination="product.info.main" after="product.info.overview"/>
        <move element="product.info.main" destination="content" after="product.info.media"/>
        <referenceContainer name="columns">
            <block class="Smartwave\Porto\Block\Template" name="side_popup" after="-" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/side_popup.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

To avoid affecting all products on the website I have tried entering code in the product design tab in admin panel in the  Layout Update XML
Code I tried was

```
<move element="product.info.stock.sku" destination="sidebar.additional" after="product_view_custom_block"/>
```

This moved the element but lost the formatting.
I then tried to move the customisation box that requests the name using:

```
<move element="product.add.form" destination="sidebar.additional" after="product.info.stock.sku"/>
```

This didn't do anything.

How do you find out what the element names are as when I view the code from the page the element names are not there.

Hope this makes sense

Andy

So I've been having a play around with this.
I added the code

```
<move element="product.info.price" destination="sidebar.additional" after="product_view_custom_block"/>
```

This produced the following result

[image]

It moved the element but lost the formatting.
When I add

```
<move element="product.social.links" destination="sidebar.additional" after="product.info.price"/>
<move element="product.reviews.summary" destination="sidebar.additional" after="product.social.links"/>
```

Nothing moves. Can anyone tell me why some elements move and some don't.
The product custom box I think is called **product.add.form** which includes the "**Add to cart**" button but this doesn't move either.
So confused